# UseRawInputEncoding and Norwegian letters

Tags: listings, languages, input-encodings

I'm currently writing a document in overleaf that has a lot of code implemented in the `lstlisting` environment. The problem with this is that it floods my log with "invalid utf-8 byte sequence error ". These are not fatal errors, but they are annoying. I've solved this with the command:

```
\UseRawInputEncoding
```

But now my norwegian special characters `æ`, `ø` and `å` have disappeared, and that is not good.
Is there any way to solve both these issues without causing new issues? Like exemting the charactes from the command? I have used the package `[utf8]{inputenc}`

Comment: you normally shouldn't use `\UseRawInputEncoding`. normally non-ascii chars in listings can be handled easiest with the literate option.

Comment: You almost certainly don't want to use Raw encoding (that is essentially meaningless as an input format) on a local installation you could (if you _really_need to)  `\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}` and save the file in latin-1 (iso-8859-1) but I think overleaf requires utf-8 in the editor (you might want to check).  Better would be to resolve whatever the issue is you are having with listings, the listingsutf8 package may help